# designer not loading latest version of document

Tags: sharepoint-designer, versioning, bug

I am creating a branding solution for SharePoint 2013 and using SharePoint Designer 2013 to edit one of the OOB master pages and the CSS and custom javascript for the solution.  My problem is that when I save the changes things basically work OK, but after saving, checking in, and coming back to the files after the weekend, once I make more changes my previously saved and checked in changes are gone and I have to re-do some amount of work.  Why is this and how can I fix it?  When I open a document in SharePoint Designer it should default to giving me the latest version, not some unknown previous version; which is what it appears to be doing.

**Update:**  Issue ongoing.

Additional information - When I started work on this site I had a SharePoint 2010 site open, in SPD 2010, as well to copy some things and review similar source files.  I by no means was using SPD 2010 to edit anything in my SP 2013 site, or vice-versa, but both applications were open at once.

I've taken to saving my source in a separate text file so I can copy/paste if I somehow get an old version instead of the current version.  My next step when I get a little more time will be removing and reinstalling SharePoint Designer 2013.

**Update:** Issue Ongoing - response from MPN mod

They told me to contact MS Support.  I'll probably try reinstalling the software before burning one of our tickets for the year.

**Update 2:** Issue Ongoing

I managed to get around some of this by using NotePad ++ and the drag-and-drop web UI to do the CSS files.  Designer seems to be doing OK for the master page editing but seems to crash if I try to check in and publish, then check out and re-open the master page in the same session.  Soon I'll re-install this pig.

Comment: Not to ask too stupid of a question, but this may or may not have happened to me before: you state you've saved and checked in the page; have you published it yet? If you only check the page in, it saves as a minor version. SharePoint, in turn, will only display the last major version of a page to users other than the creator.

Comment: Yes I did check in and publish because I wanted to share the changes with everyone with access to the site.  Regardless, when I came back to edit it, I should have gotten the latest version - minor or major - because I was the only person to ever edit the document, and I have admin rights.  Likewise I should have seen the latest version when I went to view the page in question.